# How to use a pandas DataFrame as data parameter in Seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

Looking at the [`lmplot` documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html), it shows

> Parameters:
>
> ```
>       x, y : strings, optional
>
>             Input variables; these should be column names in data.
>
>       data : DataFrame
>
>               Tidy (“long-form”) dataframe where each column 
>               is a variable and each row is an observation.
> ```

I have a pandas dataframe `customers` that I would like to use as a parameter for a `lmplot`. How can I transform my pandas dataframe into a tidy ("long-form") dataframe for use in `lmplot`?

Currently, I'm trying to do the following:

```
sns.lmplot(customers["Length of Membership"], customers["Yearly Amount Spent"], customers)
```

(Seaborn is imported as `sns`). The python code above returns an error that contains a very long list of floating points.

Comment: Looks like the first two args (x and y) are expected to be strings, but you're passing two Series.  Try `sns.lmplot("Length of Membership", "Yearly Amount Spent", customers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Bob Haffner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3437504/bob-haffner), looking closer at the documentation, the DataFrame wasn't the issue at all, rather, the X and Y parameters I was passing.

I was passing in Series, when I should have been passing in strings, as such:

```
sns.lmplot("Length of Membership", "Yearly Amount Spent", customers)
```